# Use a function in one class in other without inheritance in c++

Tags: c++, oop

The situation is like this:

```
//header file

#ifndef CLASSA_H
#define CLASSA_H

#include <stdint.h>

class ClassA
{
public:
    void function1();

    void function2();
};

#endif //CLASSA_H
```

```
//cpp file
#include "ClassA.h"
void ClassA::function1()
{
    /* some code */
}
void ClassA::function2()
{
    /* some more code */
}
void function3()
{
    /* more code /*
}
```

```
//main.cpp
#include "ClassA.h"
int main()
{
    ClassA obj;
    obj.function3();
}
```

I want to call function3() in main.cpp but without inheritance. I tried using the instance of ClassA but that says "function3 is not a member of classA".
Maybe I'm missing a concept, would be great if anyone can help.

Comment: `obj.function3();` calls a member function of a class. If you just want to call the function, do `function3();`. The answer depends on whether `function3` should be a part of a class or not.

Comment: What do you expect `obj.function3()` to do that just a `function3()` does not do?

Comment: by doing just function3(); it says "function3 was not declared in this scope"

Comment: `function3()` is not a `ClassA` member function, it can't be called like that.

Comment: @metal_dent, you need to declare it in the header file `void function3();` but outside the class.

Comment: @anastaciu can't it be done without declaring in the header?

Comment: @metal_dent, you are including the header file in main, if it's not declared there, `main` doesn't know of its existence.

Comment: @metal_dent, you dont need to define it there, just a declaration `void function3();`.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to call `function3()` with `obj.function3()` syntax, the compiler then tries to find if there's a function exists named `function3` in the instance of the class (i.e. object).

Now, in this case, you can do two things:

1. Include `void function3()` in the `public:` of the class and change `void function3()` to `void ClassA :: function3()` to tell the compiler that the containing code is defined for the class member function.
2. Or, define the function inside the header file and prevent calling the function by defining the class object. It's obvious, isnce you can't access something which is declared outside of the class.

---

The code explanation of all the two above methods is as follows:

### Method 1

#### `ClassA.cpp`

```
#include "ClassA.h"
...
void ClassA::function3() // definition of the class member function
{
    /* more code */
}
```

#### `main.cpp`

```
#include "ClassA.h"
int main()
{
    ClassA obj;
    obj.function3(); // now it's inside the class member function
                     // hence, we may now use it
}
```

#### `ClassA.h`

```
...
class ClassA
{
public:
    ...
    void function3(); // declared inside the class
};

#endif //CLASSA_H
```

---

### Method 2

#### `ClassA.h`

```
...
void function3()
{
    /* more code */
}
```

#### `main.cpp`

```
#include "ClassA.h"
int main()
{
    function3();
}
```

#### `ClassA.cpp`

```
class {
    ...
};

void function3()
{
    /* more code */
}
```

---

But the second method will make the class useless, therefore, possibly you meant to achieve the first method and not the second.